# C# append text to a certain line

Tags: c#, file

I try to build some table inside a text file which 
look like this:

```
Name           Grade

--------------------
John           100

Mike           94
...
...
```

I have this bunch of code:

```
List<string> NamesList = new List<string>();
            List<int> Grades = new List<int>();
            Grades.Add(98);
            Grades.Add(100);
            NamesList.Add("John");
            NamesList.Add("Alon");



            if (NamesList.Count() == Grades.Count())
            {
                var length = NamesList.Count();
                var min = Grades.Min();
                var max = Grades.Max();
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter myF =
                    new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\axcel\textfolder\myFile.txt", true))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            myF.WriteLine("Name           Age           Grade");
                            myF.WriteLine("==================================");
                        }

                        myF.WriteLine(NamesList.ElementAt(i));
                        myF.WriteLine("         ");
                        myF.WriteLine(Grades.ElementAt(i));

                    }
                }

            }
```

but my problem is that writing the grades after the names it is writing in a new line. I thought of writing it together to a string and to streaming it but I want to avoid an extra computing...
How can I solve it?

Comment: I would highly encourage you to give a try to the FileHelpers library. It will help you so much writing/reading files.

Comment: Did u try replace "Write" instead of "WriteLine"?

Comment: You're calling `WriteLine` and surprised you get new lines?

Comment: Might be a good idea to create a Student class (with name and grade) instead of having two collections.

Comment: Name, grade should be property of an object Student. Student should expose the projection methode that you need to convert from a student object to a string representation either by adding a method or ovewriting `ToString` if you have to store data please use a know format: either Json or Csv will be readable enough fo simple class like this. This presentation look like for diplay only that reinforce the need of using projection method or ToString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue you are having, you could just use:
`myF.WriteLine(NamesList.ElementAt(i) + "         " + Grades.ElementAt(i));`

However the code you provided would benefit from being modified as described in the comments (create a class, use FileHelpers, etc.)

Comment: Is the inner space length between Name and Grade can be controlable so columns will "look good"? For example: if total space chars are 15 so if name is 7 chars the space will be 15-7=8 chars

Comment: You could do `myF.WriteLine(NamesList.ElementAt(i).PadRight(totalLength - (NamesList.ElementAt(i).Length + Grades.ElementAt(i).Length), ' ') + Grades.ElementAt(i))` but as I said before, I strongly suggest you take the other suggestions onboard :-p - @TVOHM solution is a lot better than the quick fix I gave you...

Answer (score 4):

`WriteLine()` always add a new line after your text. So in your case it should be

```
 myF.Write(NamesList.ElementAt(i));
 myF.Write("         ");
 myF.WriteLine(Grades.ElementAt(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var students = new List<(string name, int age, int grade)>()
{
    ("John", 21, 98),
    ("Alon", 45, 100)
};

students.Add(("Alice", 35, 99));

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("myFile.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", "Name", "Age", "Grade"));

    foreach(var student in students)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", student.name, student.age, student.grade));
    }
}
```

As some comments have suggested you could use a Student class to group name, age and grade. In this example I've used a [Value Tuple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) instead.

You can see how it improves the readability of the code and you can focus on the problem you are actually trying to solve. You can reduce your write operation to a simple, readable expression - meaning you are less likely to make mistakes like mixing up Write and WriteLine.

Answer (score 2):

You can always align the text by using string interpolation alignment.

To follow some of the comments, I also urge you to build a class holding the values.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code using string interpolation alignment

```
var students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student {Name = "John", Age = 10, Grade = 98},
    new Student {Name = "Alon", Age = 10, Grade = 100}
};

var minGrade = students.Min(s => s.Grade);
var maxGrade = students.Max(s => s.Grade);

using (var myF = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\axcel\textfolder\myFile.txt", true))
{
    myF.WriteLine($"{"Name",-15}{"Age",-10}{"Grade",5}");
    myF.WriteLine("==============================");

    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        myF.WriteLine($"{student.Name,-15}{student.Age,-10}{student.Grade,5}");
    }
}
```

This will produce the following result:

```
Name           Age       Grade
==============================
John           10           98
Alon           10          100
```

Positive numbers are right-aligned and negative numbers are left-aligned

You can read more about it on the [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) page at Microsoft Docs

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:
Why you are not trying the concatenating the two string like:

```
   string line = NamesList.ElementAt(i) + "         " + Grades.ElementAt(i);
   myF.WriteLine(line);
```

OR
Solution 2:
What you are using is WriteLine("Text") function which always writes the text to next line. Instead you can use Write("Text") function which will write the string on same line. you can try like:

```
myF.Write(NamesList.ElementAt(i));
myF.Write("         ");
myF.Write(Grades.ElementAt(i));
myF.WriteLine(); // Here it will enter to new line
```